# WireMock - invalid content-length after modify body by ResponseTransformer

Tags: wiremock

I'm trying to modify response with wiremock in record mode.
I'm extending **ResponseTransformer** and replace an absolute url reference.
Wiremock returns modified response but doesn't update Content-Length header so chrome thinks there is few more bytes to download.
When i try add Content-Length header by :

...
`Response.Builder.like(response).headers(updateContentLength(response.getHeaders(), modifiedBody.length()));`
...

```
private HttpHeaders updateContentLength(HttpHeaders headers, int bodyLength) {
    HttpHeaders newHttpHeaders = HttpHeaders.noHeaders();

    for (HttpHeader header : headers.all()) {

        if(header.key().equalsIgnoreCase("Content-Length"))
        {
            newHttpHeaders.plus(new HttpHeader(header.key(), bodyLength +""));
        }
        else
        {
            newHttpHeaders.plus(header);
        }
    }
    return  newHttpHeaders;
}
```

Some headers like Set-Cookie disappears
and "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" is added extra.

using:
wiremock-standalone-2.14.0.jar

Comment: I created issue for this https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The bug is reporoted here github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/907

2) My workaround is to not change actual content length by adding white characters in a place where a client ignores them e.g.

```
<script src="https://example123456.com/aaa"></script>
```

replace by:

```
<script src=      "https://example.com/aaa"></script>
```